# ORA 01918: user '...' does not exist

Tags: oracle, users

I am new to Oracle DB and I am currently working with Oracle Database 21c express edition.
After the installation, I created a common user "C##OLUAKIN" so that I don't have to do my work on the SYS or SYSTEM users. At the beginning, things were fine, I created a container database "sqlp" and connected to this database with the new common user "C##OLUAKIN" which I created.

**Now, this is the problem:** I have created another container database "testatmdb" but I am not able to connect to this database using the C##OLUAKIN user, it returns the error "Status : Failure -Test failed: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied" [image]

**1).** I have tried to logon to Sqlplus using the user C##OLUAKIN, I get the same error "ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied"[image]

**2).** I have tried to change the password of the C##OLUAKIN user by logging on as sysdba and using the alter user command as below;

```
         alter user C##OLUAKIN identified by Oluakin0823;
```

but I get error "ORA-01918: user 'C##OLUAKIN' does not exist"[image]

**3).** I logged on using the SYSTEM user on sql developer and I viewed all users with the query below;

```
       Select * from all_users;
```

the common user "C##OLUAKIN" which I created was not found in the list of users.

The puzzling thing however is that I am able to connect to the other container database "sqlp" using this C##OLUAKIN user which the system claims does not exist. In fact, while logged on to this database, if I query to check the current user, by running

```
     select * from user_users;
```

the query returns C##OLUAKIN as the current user as seen below
[image]

So, I am confused.
*Why am I not able to use the C##OLUAKIN user being a common user to connect to another container database?
*Why is the C##OLUAKIN user missing in the list of all_users?
*Why is the user reported as not existing even though I am able to connect to a database through the same user?

Please help.

Comment: So, it seems you believe you have two Container Data Base (CDB) instances on one server, but do you really have one CDB, with two Pluggable Databases (PDBs), named `sqlp` and `testatmdb`?  When you first installed Oracle Database Express Edition, by default, it would have created a CDB named `CDB$ROOT`.  A common user is common just within a CDB, and possibly accessible to the PDBs.  I didn't wade through all your screenshots, but can you [edit] your question to clarify?